# C# WebHttpRequest how to add multiple headers?

Tags: c#, .net, authorization, httpwebrequest

So basically I have code like this and I want to send request using this function where I had to add additional headers Authorization and STW-Authorization:

```cs
public static string postXMLData(string destinationUrl, string requestXml)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationUrl);
        byte[] bytes;
        bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic bXNlcnZlcjp0ZXN0");
        request.Headers.Add("STW-Authoriztaion", "Basic bXNlcnZlcjp0ZXN0");
        request.Method = "POST";
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
            return responseStr;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The problem is that I receive all the time

```
$exception  {"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}    System.Net.WebException
```

I suppose that, there is a problem with headers because in Visual Studio on request preview it looks like this:

```json
{Content-Type: application/xmlContent-Length: 728Authorization: Basic bXNlcnZlcjp0ZXN0STW-Authoriztaion: Basic bXNlcnZlcjp0ZXN0}
```

There is no any delimiters such as "," in this JSON, and string values are not in " ". How to solve it, or how to send it with success? Doing it with Postman works.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check the spelling of "STW-Authori**zt**aion". I guess it was supposed to be "STW-Authori**zat**ion.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, my bad, now it works as it should be. Thanks a lot